# Installed libjava3d-java but cannot compile my Java3D project

Tags: java

On my Mac, I can easily compile a Java project using Java3D. On a plain Maverick with default-jdk, I get a lot of errors:

```
./DreiDimAnsicht.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Canvas3D
location: class DreiDimAnsicht
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(config); 
                              ^
```

So I installed the `libjava3d-java` package but it gives me the exact same error messages. Since I want to use Launchpad's build service, I cannot just install some stuff on my machine to get it to work. Is there some package that I can install to get the compilation to work?

I compile it with a plain `javac MainClass.java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the jars to the classpath when compiling and when running the final jar file with the application.

When compiling:

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/j3dcore.jar:/usr/share/java/j3dutils.jar:/usr/share/java/vecmath.jar MainClass.jar
```

To specify the classpath when running the jar, put the classpath in the manifest file. Add the following line:

```
Class-Path: /usr/share/java/j3dcore.jar /usr/share/java/j3dutils.jar /usr/share/java/vecmath.jar
```